# Netbeans - cannot find make.exe , "cygdrive/" is pre-added to PATH

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile, mingw

Trying to compile c++ in NetBeans. I'm using MakeGW as tool collection.

```
/usr/bin/which: no pkg-config in (/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Borland/Delphi7/Bin:/cygdrive/c/Borland/Delphi7/Projects/Bpl:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/PC Connectivity Solution:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/DMIX:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/NTRU Cryptosystems/NTRU TCG Software Stack/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Wave Systems Corp/Gemalto/Access Client/v5:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Roxio Shared/DLLShared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Roxio Shared/10.0/DLLShared:/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin:/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin)
```

make: pkg-config: Command not found

make: *** [.build-pre] Error 127

My PATH is"

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\;C:\MinGW\bin
```

I don't understand why it does even mention cygwin

Comment: Now , have you download GTK+2 ?

Answer (score 0):

**preparing to use PKG-CONFIG**

in some case, pkg-config doesn't comes with MinGW and MSYS.
Installing pkg-config on Windows is not that easy .

Look here how you can do it.

[mingw how to](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/mingw_how_to.html)

- Don't worry about `cygdrive` netbeans doing its own logic.
- add also C:\MinGW to your Path
- I have also C:\msys\1.0\bin in the path and I have put it before the c:\mingw setting.

Comment: I did what you said,but now it says:   `Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing gtk+-2.0.pc
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
make: *** [.build-pre] Error 1`  There are some fixes for this but for Linux

Comment: You can find GTK+ here [GTK+2](http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php) . Scroll down to the download section.

Answer (score 0):

Your second reply about gtk+-2.0 not being found in the "pkg-config search path" relates to the environmental variable that pkg-config uses to find library files.

In windows, the environment variable is called PKG_CONFIG_PATH and is found under My Computer/Properties/Advanced/Environment Variables, I have to admit that I don't run Linux but here is a link to an explanation of environment variables in linux:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_Variables

I hope this helps.